# Swift how to read through all indexes of array using for loop with index [i]

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, arraylist, element

The Code I have so far only does for 1 index however I want it to read all existing indexes within the array. element array can carry many groups of numbers for example 
Array ["2,2,5" , "5,2,1"] contains 2 indexes [0] and [1]

```
var element = Array[0]
let splitData = element.components(separatedBy: ",")

// split data will always contain 3 values.
var value1 = splitData[0]
var value2 = splitData[1]
var value3 = splitData[2]

print("value 1 is : " + value1 + " value 2 is : " + value2 + " value 3 is: " + value3)
```

the output of this code when `Array ["2,2,5" , "5,2,1"]` is :

```
value 1 is : 2 value 2 is : 2 value 3 is : 5
```

As the output suggests how can i iterate through all indexes of Array to display each of their 3 values.

I want the output to be :

```
value 1 is : 2 value 2 is : 2 value 3 is : 5
value 1 is : 5 value 2 is : 2 value 3 is : 1
```

I believe I need to use a for loop however I am unsure how to apply it to this. I am quite new to coding. Any help will be Appreciated

Comment: You mention using a `for` loop but your code makes no attempt to use a loop. Show your attempt to use a loop.

Comment: You say you are unsure how to use a loop so I think you’re much better off reading up on [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) in a long term perspective rather than looking for a quick solution here. The Apple documentation is really good in my opinion.

Comment: @rmaddy I have created a for loop however i did not know what to put as argument  for i in 0..<array.count { } was wat i was lacking.

Comment: It would have been helpful to put that info in your original question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
    var element = array[i]
    let splitData = element.components(separatedBy: ",")

    // split data will always contain 3 values.
    var value1 = splitData[0]
    var value2 = splitData[1]
    var value3 = splitData[2]

    print("value 1 is : " + value1 + " value 2 is : " + value2 + " value 3 is: " + value3)
}
```

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, could you make it compile by changing Array[i] to array[i]

Answer (score 5):

here are two solutions you can use, depending on what is the best result for you.

1) If your goal is to transform an array like `["3,4,5", "5,6", "1", "4,9,0"]` into a **flattened** version `["3", "4", "5", "5", "6", "1", "4", "9", "0"]` you can do it easily with the `flatMap` operator in the following way:

```
let myArray = ["3,4,5", "5,6", "1", "4,9,0"]
let flattenedArray = myArray.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: ",") }
```

Then you can iterate on it like every other array,

```
for (index, element) in myArray.enumerated() {
    print("value \(index) is: \(element)")
}
```

2) If you just want to iterate over it **and keep the levels** you can use the following code.

```
let myArray = ["3,4,5", "5,6", "1", "4,9,0"]

for elementsSeparatedByCommas in myArray {
    let elements = elementsSeparatedByCommas.components(separatedBy: ",")
    print(elements.enumerated().map { "value \($0) is: \($1)" }.joined(separator: " "))
}
```

Hope that helps!